# Creating behaviour that is both like a JavaScript object literal as a function

Tags: javascript

I'd like to be able to do the following:

```
person('male');
person.age(34);
```

As you can see, I want the `person object` to be both a `function` as an `object`. What I mean is that doing so:

```
function person(gender){

    this.gender = gender || 'unknown';
}
```

excludes me from doing so:

```
person.gender; // undefined
```

unless I create a new object from the person function, like so:

```
var me = new person();
me.gender; // 'unknown'
```

which I do not want, as I still want to be able to set other properties, like so:

```
person.age = 34;
```

**Is this even possible? Of am I trying to accomplish the impossible?**

To clarify: I don't want to need to create instances. The key is that I just want to be able to both call the function `person` as call a `function.property()`.

**EDIT**: Perhaps I've confused many (including myself) by using a wrong example. A simpler question would be: How would I be able to call a function and a 'property' of that function, like so:

```
car();
car.start();
```

both at the same time without the need to create an instance of car?

Comment: Functions *are* objects

Comment: Yeah, I know. I want the behaviour as described above, generally considered behaviour from both object literals as functions.

Comment: For the one(s) down voting: please let me know why so I can adjust my question. (instead of just down voting)

Comment: I was about to say the same as @Brandon but then I thought your problem may more interesting than that and that's why I ask you to clarify the question, because after reading it 4 times I still don't get what exactly you want.

Comment: What's wrong with using `person` as a constructor? Nothing prevents you from adding properties to instances created by it, or to the constructor itself (these are generally referred to as static properties). Your final example seems about right, but the last line should be `me.age = 34` since the age applies to an instance, not to all people.

Comment: I don't want to need to create instances. I find it ugly and unnecessary to write: `var me = new person(); me.age = 10;` I don't want to create instances.

Comment: you can do what you are asking.. i think your issue is that for `gender`, you are attempting to use `this.gender` which makes no sense because you **aren't** using an instance of `person`. There's no context for `this`. You should use    `person.gender = gender || 'unknown';`

Comment: @Kriem - So do you want `person` to return a new person or will you only ever have a single "person" at a time? If the former then use `person` as a constructor. If the latter just use an object literal.

Comment: @JamesAllardice - Yes, I'd like to create new persons. But as stated in my addendum, I'd like to write both `person()` as `person.age()` without creating instances.

Comment: so what syntax do you propose to use that would create new instances of `person` that isn't "ugly"? Also, I kinda feel like you are misunderstanding how objects work in general. You say you want to create new persons but you don't want to create instances. Well what do you think "creating new persons" means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `this` inside your function, which refers to the Object instance created when running this function as a constructor by invoking it with the `new` operator you can use `arguments.callee` to refer to the function itself

```
function person(gender){
    arguments.callee.gender = gender || 'unknown';
}
```

If you want to ensure that a function is always used as a constructor even if invoked without the `new` operator, you can do it by implicitly invoking it.

```
function person(gender){
    if(!(this instanceof person)){ return new person(gender); }
    this.gender = gender || 'unknown';
}
```

In all other regards functions can do anything regular objects can, that's why they are often described as "first class objects".

You can simply assign them properties like objects, or methods like

```
function car(){
}
car.start = function(){

}
```

You can also let them inherit methods from a function using the `__proto__` property.

```
function bird(){}
function platypus(){}

bird.layEggs = function(){};
platypus.__proto__ = bird;
platypus.layEggs()         // now you know
```

Answer (score 4):

We might be able to give a better answer if you would explain the motivation behind what you want to do. However, yes, what you describe is possible. In JavaScript, functions are just another type of object. That means that you could define a function, then set properties on it like so:

```
var person = function () {
    return "Hi, I am a person!";
};

person.species = "human";
person.foo = 42;

console.log( person() ); // prints: Hi, I am a person!
console.log( person.species ): // prints: human
console.log( person.foo ); // prints: 42
```

Or working from your second example:

```
var car = function () {
    return {
        model: "Focus",
        make: "Ford",
        year: 2010
    };
};

car.start = function () {
    return "Vroom!";
};

console.log ( car.make ); // prints: Ford
console.log ( car.start() ); // prints Vroom!
```

By the way, this is **not** the same as a function that returns an object. That might look like this:

```
var person = function () {
    return {
        species: "human",
        name: "Bob",
        age: 27
    };
};

var bob = person();
bob.occupation = "cubicle drone";

console.log( bob.name ); // prints: Bob
console.log( bob.occupation ); // prints: cubicle drone
console.log( person.occupation ); // prints: undefined
console.log( bob == person ); // prints: false
```

Variables `bob` and `person` both hold objects, but not the same object, not even the same type of object.

Comment: Fixed typo (thanks Kyle!) Pointed out difference from returning an object.

Comment: No problem i assumed that is what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

a small example using the instanceof way that @Winchestro is using

on jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/47EEr/

```
'use strict';
function person(gender, age, name) {
    if (!(this instanceof person)) {
        return new person(gender, age, name);
    }
    var props = { gender: '', age: 0, name: '' }, fnCreateProp = function(prop, value) {
        Object.defineProperty(this, prop, {
            get: function() {
                return props[prop];
            },
            set: function(val) {
                console.log('setting prop ' + prop + ' to ' + val);
                props[prop] = val;
            }
        });
    }.bind(this);

    for (var prop in props) {
        if (!props.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            continue;
        }
        fnCreateProp(prop, props[prop]);
    }

    this.gender = gender;
    this.age = age;
    this.name = name;    

    this.toString = function(element) {
        var str = '[Person=(';
        for (var prop in props) {
            if (!props.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                continue;
            }
            if (str.indexOf('(') !== str.length-1) {
                str += ',';
            }
            str += prop +': ' + props[prop];
        }
        str += ')]';
        if (typeof element !== 'undefined') {
            var el = document.getElementById(element);
            if (el) {
                el.innerHTML = str;
            }
        }
        return str;
    };

    this.birthday = function() {
        this.age++;
    };
}

var p1 = person('male', 33, 'male 1');
var p2 = new person();
p2.age = 32; p2.gender = 'female'; p2.name = 'female 1';

p1.toString('person1');
p2.toString('person2');
p2.birthday();
p2.toString('person2birthday');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
function person(gender){  
  return {
    gender: gender || 'unknown'
  };
}
var p = person('male');
p.age = 34;
p.name = 'John';
etc...
```

No "new" is used and you can still re-use the person function.

Answer (score 0):

**Your edit:**

> **EDIT**: Perhaps I've confused many (including myself) by using a wrong example. A simpler question would be: How would I be able to
>   call a function and a 'property' of that function, like so:
>
> ```
> car();
> car.start();
> ```
>
> both at the same time without the need to create an instance of car?

**Is this what you are looking for?**

```
function car() {

  console.log("car called");

  car.start = function() {
    console.log("car.start called");
  }

}
car();
car.start();

/**** output:****
car called
car.start called
*/
```